# Finding the number of positive integers $x$ such that $\log_{(x/9)}\left(\frac{x^2}{3}\right)<6+\log_{(3)}\left(\frac{9}{x}\right)$

Tags: logarithms

> Find the number of positive integers $x$, such that $$\log_{(x/9)}\left(\frac{x^2}{3}\right) < 6 + \log_{(3)}\left(\frac{9}{x}\right); 1≤x≤100, x≠9$$

Here's what I did:

Using Base Changing Theorem, the inequality can be written as
$${\log(x^2/3)\over \log(x/9)} < 6+ {\log(9/x)\over \log(3)}$$
Simplifying it I ended up here:
$$ 17(\log (3))²+8\log(x)\log(3)-(\log(x))^2>0$$

After eliminating $log3$, and solving the quadratic in $logx$, I got
$$ (logx -4+ \sqrt33)(logx-4- \sqrt33)<0.$$
But this doesn't seem to be the right answer.

What should I do next?

Comment: Looks like a quadratic in $\log x$...

Comment: @abiessu Yes, pretty much

Comment: Given that, you could either substitute $y=\log x$ and solve for $y$ or solve for $\log x$ directly

Comment: Can we consider the base of log to be 3,  and eliminate log 3?

Comment: There's no need to eliminate $\log$ at this stage, but if you wanted to you could do that.

Comment: @abiessu ohk thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite getting what you got. I shall use the shorthand expression $\log x=l$.
$$\frac {2l-\log 3}{l-2\log 3}-\frac {2\log3-l}{\log 3}<6$$
$$\frac {l^2-2l\log 3 +3(\log 3)^2}{\log 3(l-2\log 3)}-6<0$$
$$\frac {l^2-8l\log 3+15(\log 3)^2}{l-2\log 3}<0$$
$$\frac {(l-3\log 3)(l-5\log 3)}{(l-2\log 3)}<0$$
Hence, $l \in (-\infty, 2\log 3)\cup (3\log 3,5\log 3)$
or $x\in (0,9)\cup (27, 243)$.

**PS:**

Here properties of logarithm have been used, including-

●$\log(\frac ab)=\log a-\log b$

●$\log(x^a)=a\log x$

Comment: Yes , I got it thanks

Answer (score 4):

Multiply the equation with -1, then the equation will look like P(log(x)) < 0. Find both the roots and region between the roots will belong to possible values of x which satisfies the given constraints.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, I did it twice